# StoreKit2 Transaction.currentEntitlements doesn't return auto-renewals

Tags: swift, storekit, storekit2

**How do I get `Transaction.currentEntitlements` to return subscription auto-renewal transactions that happen while the app is closed?**

---

I have implemented auto-renewing subscriptions in my macOS app.

I have a `StoreManager` that creates listeners on `Transaction.currentEntitlements` and `Transaction.updates`

If the subscription renews while the app is running, `Transaction.updates` receives the latest transactions, as expected.

However, When a renewal happens automatically while the app is *not* running, when the app is re-opened the `Transaction.currentEntitlements` does *not* return the renewal transaction.

Following the steps to reproduce:

- Start the app and purchase an auto-renewing subscription
- kill the app
- wait for the subscription to expire and auto renew (monthly can be set to renew every 30 seconds when testing)
- restart the app
- `Transaction.currentEntitlements` returns nothing.

Checking the **StoreKit Transactions** debugging window when the app starts, renewal transactions that happened while the app was closed show as "not finished".

[image]

The non-finished transactions are the ones not returned.

If the subscription again gets renewed while the app is running, the listener on `Transaction.updates` gets fired and the new renewal plus any non-finished transactions are returned.

Here's the relevant code from the `StoreManager`

```
@MainActor
class StoreManager: ObservableObject {
    
    var updates: Task<Void, Never>? = nil
    var transactions: Task<Void, Never>? = nil

    init() {
        updates = updatesListenerTask()
        transactions = transactionsListenerTask()
    }

    @Published private (set) var transaction: StoreKit.Transaction?
    
    func updatesListenerTask() -> Task<Void, Never> {
        Task.detached(priority: .background) {
            for await result in Transaction.updates {
                Task { @MainActor in
                    do {
                        let transaction = try self.validateResult(result)
                        self.transaction = transaction
                        await transaction.finish()
                    } catch {
                        print("Failed verification =\(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func transactionsListenerTask() -> Task<Void, Never> {
        Task.detached(priority: .background) {
            for await result in Transaction.currentEntitlements {
                Task { @MainActor in
                    do {
                        let transaction = try self.validateResult(result)
                        self.transaction = transaction
                        await transaction.finish()
                    } catch {
                        print("Failed verification =\(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func validateResult(_ result: VerificationResult<StoreKit.Transaction>) throws -> StoreKit.Transaction {
        switch result {
        case let .verified(transaction):
            return transaction
        case .unverified:
            throw StoreManagerError.failedVerification
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Update*

`Transaction.latest(for: <productId>)` returns the latest finished product, so not the auto renewed one.

Comment: So is StoreKit 2 essentially broken when it comes to auto-renewing subscriptions? I'm currently updating my code from StoreKit 1 (App Store receipt verification) to StoreKit 2 (Transaction.currentEntitlements). But if currentEntitlements doesn't work correctly, then I might as well stick with StoreKit 1.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this problem in Xcode with an iOS app. This seems like such basic functionality that it's strange that it still hasn't been fixed after more than 18 months. Any idea if this is just an Xcode testing issue or does it affect apps in the wild?

Comment: _"is StoreKit 2 essentially broken?"_… seems like it. My subscriptions are annual, so hopefully it'll be fixed by the time anyone wants to renew!

Comment: The main issue seems to be the auto-renew transaction failing to complete (as indicated by the warning icon in the Transactions window). However, this thread suggests that it's simply an Xcode testing bug: "Just got confirmation from someone working on this that it's just a bug in StoreKit testing when using StoreKit 2 - phew!" https://twitter.com/hybridcattt/status/1496131281792421899